# Ext JS Panel Won't Scroll

Tags: extjs, panel, autoscroll

I have a popup windows which is suppose to show an email (which is in html) in the `centerPanel`. That panel is in the `center` region of the border layout.

It absolutely has `autoscroll` set to `true` and I know that my test data is much larger than the panel.  But I can't get it to scroll.

Is there, perhaps, a better way of setting this up?  I've tried some other object like a `label`, `display`, `textarea` etc. as an item in the `center` panel and set that object with `autoscroll : true` with no success

```
popup = new Ext.Window({
    width: 900,
    height: 320,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    id: 'popupWindow',

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [
        // ...
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            id: 'centerPanel',
            autoscroll: true,
            margin: '0 5 0 5',
            html: jsonData.email
        },
        // ...
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I had to add overflowY: 'scroll' to the center panel.

Comment: I this case you should mark your own answer as solution to show other users that your question has already been solved.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `autoScroll`, not `autoscroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Thev's answer is correct; however, it depends upon which version of Ext JS you are using (read below).

`autoscroll` means nothing to Ext JS, specifically. It becomes a new Javascript property entirely distinct from `autoScroll` due to the casing.

Watch out, though: Ext's [5.1 Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-autoScroll) specifies that `autoScroll` is now deprecated and that `scrollable` (with the appropriate configuration) should be used, instead.